# PowerShell Import-Csv issue

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV that has 3 columns: username, fullname and path. I have a script that prompts the user for their full name then reads the CSV and picks out the row that pertains to that user. I can run the commands manually at a console and they work fine, but when I run them in a script I get nothing.

This is the line from the script:

```
$userdata = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile" |
            Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq "$userinput" }
```

If I run this command from the console (supplying values for `$csvfile` and `$userinput`) I get the expected row being returned from the CSV. If I run it from a script I get nothing. No errors or anything, so it is obviously finding the file OK.

Comment: As an aside: you need the `"..."` neither around `$CsvFile` nor around `$userinput`. Without knowing the variable values and the input data, it's impossible to diagnose your problem. Please update your question with an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as you can get to one.

Comment: how are you running the script? what is IN the script? the code you show is NOT the code you are running ... it's only a pair of lines that are working. [*grin*]

Comment: Try and add in a `write-output $CsvFile` above that and double check the path is valid when you are running it as a script.

Comment: What are you entering for `$CsvFile`? Where is the actual file located? What is the working directory when you're running the script?

Comment: Possibly the variable `$CsvFile` does not contain a full path to the CSV file and the `$ErrorActionPreference` in the PowerShell script is set to either `Continue` (the default) or `SilentlyContinue`